# Autosave-chrome tool for scss in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, sass, saas

Before scss I used autosave tool for chrome on sample css files. But in rails scss, of course, it's doesn't work. What you doing for live editing? After autosave I can't switch between browser and IDE for after any css changes :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking is possible. Browsers are sandboxed to prevent direct access to the filesystem, and Chrome is probably the most-stringent of all of them.

Comment: Of couse it's possible. Here is a extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-autosave/mlejngncgiocofkcbnnpaieapabmanfl, which based on http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#event-onResourceContentCommitted

Comment: Cool extension. Is that the extension you're trying to use that is causing you grief with scss and autosave? If so, relevant to the question and should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) and [guard-sass](https://github.com/hawx/guard-sass).

Tie that in with [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) and [rack-livereload](https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload).

This setup means that you don't have to use the browser at all, it'll automatically refresh when you edit your scss files if you use it correctly.

Comment: You don't understand me. I need edit css in browser (chrome dev tool) with autosaving changes to scss. Not refreshing page after editing scss in IDE.